# Make a Blender sphere more convex / bulging

Tags: rendering, mesh, 3d-view

What Blender parameters do I need to adjust to make a UV Sphere more bulging or convex, i.e. to have its center areas look closer to and its outer areas look farther from the observer / camera?

For example, when projecting a material like the Earth map on an UV Sphere mesh below, central areas of the sphere like India, China, Indochina should look bigger or "closer" to the observer when rendering, while the outer parts towards the edges of the sphere like the North Pole, Australia, Europe or Africa should look more "into perspective" or farther from the observer (lighting is not relevant to the question). The grey background frame in the GIF below is the standard look of a Blender UV Sphere, while the white background frame is approximating the desired output when rendering:

[image: Rendering comparison]

Comment: To make the depth more to your liking, try playing with the _Focal Length_ of the camera (though you will have to move the camera afterwards to make it appear in the same position in the render - as you decrease focal length, the object appears farther away, yet more "fish-eyed"). Other options may include playing with how the object is UV Mapped.

Comment: I think the question is fine, perhaps a bit confusing. I'll try to post an answer later according to Christopher's tip, with a driver that automatically adjusts distance to the focal length so it all fits and is easy to setup...  To OP: it would be nice if you posted a .blend file with your setup and embedded (packed) texture: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @MartyFouts I know of the differences between EEVEE and Cycles, but I'm pretty sure the lighting and the render engine don't play a part in the issue I mentioned. Like you, I thought about that as well, tried adjusting those things and saw it wasn't that.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Thanks for the suggestion, as a matter of fact I already tried the Focal Length adjustment, suspecting it might have something to do with it, but either there's something wrong with my eyes or there's no discernable differences after doing that. Didn't try to adjust how the object is UV mapped though, I don't think I know how to do that...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady That would be great, if it achieves the goal (though I'm not sure it will, like I mentioned in my reply to Christopher Bennett). Regarding uploading the embedded texture .blend file on blend-exchange.com I'll try that, but I'm using a 8192x4096 (i.e. a 100 MB TIFF file) as a texture, that's why I mentioned the steps to replicate the process above. Here it is, using a smaller image: https://blend-exchange.com/b/qkKaOoVe/

Comment: @ChristopherBennett, Markus von Broady Ok, tried again - this time matching exactly the ratio between decreasing the focal length and scaling up the sphere, and it turns out you were both correct, and I was wrong in my initial assessment. I achieved my goal and I understood why the results differed between PS and Blender. Many thanks for your suggestions - if you posted this as an answer, I would have accepted it for sure, but since Robin Betts posted it instead, I'll accept his and upvote both your comments. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's important to mention, focal length doesn't affect how the sphere is perceived, other than it's apparent size. That is, changing focal length alone, doesn't affect the *"fish-eye"* effect. Increasing the focal length moves the sensor away from the pinhole, making it see less. What really alters the way an object is perceived, is the distance to the object, relatively to its size. So if you move towards/away or scale the object, it will be perceived differently - the focal length comes to play only to then return the apparent size to original, so the object continues to take the same amount of space on a 2D projection.

Stealing an image from this answer: [Radius of projected sphere in screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21649403/1149282)

[image]

Sadly the mathematics there are slightly wrong, so here it goes:

The height of the smallest triangle on the image can be calculated with trigonometry: $h = r \times \cos(\theta)$

Calculating theta: $\theta = \arcsin({r \over d})$

Therefore the radius of projected sphere: $h = r \times \cos(\arcsin({r \over d}))$

Since the Earth is not a perfect sphere, and so isn't the globe in your project, I'll just take a horizontal (X or Y, both the same) dimension of 2.5668 m as a diameter. $r = {2.5668 \over 2} = 1.2834$ Pardon for laziness.

The globe isn't perfectly aligned to the middle of camera view, so let's fix it by selecting the globe, then the camera, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> to parent, now set all camera rotations to zeroes, as well as set XY camera location to zeroes (leave Z as is), select the globe, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> to clear parent but without returning the globe to its original state, now also zero out the globe's XY location (again, leave Z as is).

To discover distance, go to *Scripting* workspace and paste this into console:

```py
(D.objects['Camera'].location - D.objects['Sphere'].location).length
```

Alternatively Add *Limit Distance* constraint to either object and set the other as the *Target*; the *Distance* field will show the distance between them, though console has more precision.

$d = 11.2784186955213$

Let's calculate current projected radius of the sphere:

$h = r \times \cos(\arcsin({r \over d}))$

$h = 1.2834 \times \cos(\arcsin({1.2834 \over 11.2784186955213}))$

$h = 1.2834 \times \cos(\arcsin({0.1137925479313552}))$

$h = 1.2834 \times \cos(6.533985970041084 ^\circ)$

$h = 1.2834 \times 0.9935045324684182$

$h = 1.275063716969968$

Let's also write the formula in the script form:

`d * cos(asin(r/d))` and since `d`istance is constant:

`r * cos(asin(r/11.2784186955213))`

and since we can't access radius directly, let's replace `r` with `s * 1.2834`, where `s` is the scale we will access in a driver:

`s * 1.2834 * cos(asin(s*1.2834/11.2784186955213))`

(that last step could be avoided by multiplying the object's scale by `1.2834` scaling the mesh inside down by the same amount, then scale would equal radius)

Now dividing calculated projected sphere radius by starting projected sphere radius (`h`$ /h$) results in a ratio of how much it increased in size:

`s * 1.2834 * cos(asin(s*1.2834/11.2784186955213)) / 1.275063716969968`

If the projected size increases, the sensor needs to get closer to the pinhole to see more, so the focal length decreases. So for inverse proportionality you need to divide the starting focal length (30 mm) by that ratio:

`30 / (s * 1.2834 * cos(asin(s*1.2834/11.2784186955213)) / 1.275063716969968)`

Add a hashtag `#` in front and paste it into the *Focal Length* field in the *Camera Properties*. It causes an error, as `s` is not known. You need to right-click the field -> <kbd>E</kbd> Edit Driver... Click on *+ Add Input Variable* button, rename the variable to `s`, change type to $(X)$ ***Transform channel***, choose *Sphere* as the object and finally *X Scale* as the type.

Now it works, which you can test by scaling the globe. Except it doesn't work properly.

The problem is, so far it's not the projected circle's size that is calculated, it's the size of the cross-section, but as that cross-section is closer and closer to the camera, it appears larger and larger, and that has to be taken into account as well.

Starting $d_1$ and dynamic `d1` need to be calculated, so another ratio can be applied: calculated distance to the cross-section, divided by the starting distance to it: `d1`$/d_1$

$d_1 = d - d_2 = d - r * \sin(\theta)$

$d_1 = 11.2784186955213 - 1.2834 * \sin(6.533985970041084 ^\circ)$

$d_1 = 11.2784186955213 - 1.2834 * 0.1137925479313552$

$d_1 = 11.2784186955213 - 0.1460413560151013$

$d_1 = 11.1323773395062$

`d1` = `11.2784186955213 - s * 1.2834 * sin(asin(s*1.2834/11.2784186955213))`

ratio: `(11.2784186955213 - s * 1.2834 * sin(asin(s*1.2834/11.2784186955213))) / 11.1323773395062`

### Final driver

This time as the distance decreases, we want the focal length to also decrease, so the proportion is not reversed and so we want to multiply by the 2nd ratio.

```py
30 / (s * 1.2834 * cos(asin(s*1.2834/11.2784186955213)) / 1.275063716969968) * ((11.2784186955213 - s * 1.2834 * sin(asin(s*1.2834/11.2784186955213))) / 11.1323773395062)
```

[image] [image]

If you scale it up so much it almost touches the camera, it will go beyond the render region, so either I'm still missing something, or it's just the limited precision of numbers in the calculation (this is also why I littered this post with such long numbers...). Or maybe not being rigorous about acquiring the radius eventually came back to me to bite me in the ass...

**Note**: Preserving the rest of the notations above, letting $F$ = starting focal length, $r$ = sphere radius, $d$ = eye to sphere center distance, $f$ = target focal length and $s$ = target scale (be aware that changing the scale also changes the radius inside of the mesh), translates the final driver formula above to the mathematical equation:

$$f = {{{F} \over {{s \times r \times \cos(\arcsin({{s \times r} \over d}))} \over {r \times \cos(\arcsin({r \over d}))}}} \times {{d - s \times r \times \sin(\arcsin({{s \times r} \over {d}}))} \over {d - r \times \sin(\arcsin({{r} \over {d}}))}}}$$
equivalent, after simplifying, reducing operands and using the fact that $\sin(\arcsin(x)) = x$ and $\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$, to:

$f = {{F \over s} \times {\sqrt{{d^2 - s^2 \times r^2} \over {d^2 - r^2}}}}$ if you need to get the focal length based on the other known values, and:
$s = {{F \times d} \over {\sqrt{F^2 \times r^2 + f^2 \times d^2 - f^2 \times r^2}}}$ if you need to get the scale based on the other known values.

The right side of these formulas can, of course, be computed either manually or written in the appropriate place via [Blender's simple expressions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#simple-expressions) if used in the driver panel, as mentioned above.

Comment: Interesting - I like math and the scripting info is useful so I'll need to take a closer look at it (I was busy today so I couldn't) to understand the idea. In my actual project (the posted .blend was just a sample to illustrate what was achieved vs what I wanted to achieve), since I'm from the N hemisphere, I work with both light and camera at X=12, Y=0, Z=5.21775, so that their rotation at X=66.5, Y=0, Z=90 sees the Earth from the sun POV at 23.5° N. Setting the camera's focal length from the default 50 mm to 35 mm seems to require an Earth scale of DefaultScale*(50/35). Am I wrong?

Comment: By the way, sorry if that wasn't clear in my question, the animation I perform in Blender is the Earth's usual one around its axis, so the focal length or scale / size stays constant, i.e. I don't animate it. Basically, I was just looking to make the Earth less flat in appearance by bulging it, to match my earliest attempt that looked more realistic from this point of view (the light angle was probably an additional cause for it, but as I said, I knew how to handle that so it wasn't considered in the question). That being said, this might prove useful for folks looking to animate bulging.

Comment: @YinCognyto You're wrong, unfortunately it's not as easy; your logic works with a plane, but with a cube changing the scale or distance (changing ratio of one to another) changes your horizon. I assumed you don't need an animation, the animation is there just to compare with Robin Betts' GIF, how here the horizon stays in place. The idea is now if you add an overlay on top (if in 3D viewport, you need to also scale that, but as mentioned, scaling a plane is easier), with transparency to compare the target Photoshop effect to the focal length.

Comment: You were right on the horizon indeed. I did my own bit of math (too long to post here) based on your last formula, the fact that `sin(asin(x))=x` and `cos(asin(x))=sqrt(1-x^2)`, and, letting F=default focal length, r=sphere radius, d=eye to sphere center distance, f=target focal length, and s=target scale, I got `f=F/s*sqrt((d^2-s^2*r^2)/(d^2-r^2))` if s is given, and `s=F*d/sqrt(F^2*r^2+f^2*d^2-f^2*r^2)` if f is given. You can confirm this if you want and add them to your answer for folks looking to set one based on the other, so I can mark your answer as the accepted one instead.

Comment: @YinCognyto this answer certainly could do with some clean up, to quote Mark Twain *"I didn't have time to write you a short letter, so I wrote you a long one."* - is `r` in your formulas just the radius inside of the mesh? Otherwise changing scale changes the radius. 

Comment: I didn't mean editing your whole answer, hence mentioning adding the bits as a "conclusion" / "note" of some sort. The variables in my formulas (which are actually your last formula, after substitutions, simplification and reducing operands) are the same ones as in your post: F=30, r=1.2834, d=11.2784186955213, with f and s either the values you set in Blender (when given) or the ones you need to get based on the other one. By the way, I tested my 1st formula (but not the 2nd) by replacing yours via edit driver in your .blend file and it seems to work and so do the values (Google agrees too).

Comment: I uploaded the whole mathematical process to get to those shorter equivalent formulas [here (MediaFire link)](https://www.mediafire.com/file/b572jxkvsw0ym6i/Blender+-+Focal+Length+&+Scale.zip/file) as a zip file containing a MS Word document and a screenshot of it. I couldn't easily strikethrough things and still keep them clear, so I added the explanations below each equal sign.

Comment: I took the liberty to suggest the edits to your answer - hope you don't mind. Feel free to adjust or refine them in case they're not clear enough ;)

Answer (score 5):

Following up on your commentary, (in particular @ChristopherBennett 's first observation,) there may be other factors, but you certainly would have to match [focal length and distance to camera].

This is a Dolly Zoom from 150mm to 15mm:

[image]

The Photoshop version is shot with a wider lens.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making everything clear to me, even posting a preview of it. I'll mark this as the accepted since it covers all points (settings involved and visual representation / proof of concept) and it's the only answer so far. I have to mention ChristopherBennett and Markus von Broady helpful comments along the same line above though, you all helped me understand what was going on and how to adjust things for a slightly better result.

Comment: @YinCognyto Thanks, on their behalf, for your consideration to the others in your conversation.. I don't mean to tread on it :).

Comment: No problem, I'm a firm believer that credit must be given where it is due. Whether this comes in the form of upvotes or marking the answer as accepted is down to the circumstances specific to each question and the feedback that was received. ;)

Comment: I don't usually change my decisions, but since Markus von Broady's answer also shows a precise way to calculate both the focal length and the scale based on the other variables when applying the transformation - all that while preserving the horizon of the sphere - I eventually chose to mark his answer as the accepted one. Hopefully it's ok with you, since my choice was strictly based on the fact that his answer is more complete, especially if one cares about technical precision. I also computed the focal length and scale the wrong way until I realized my mistake via his comments.

Comment: @Yin Cognyto Of Course! Markus'  answer is terrific! You would not even have had to explain.. but thanks for doing so :)